# About Firebase console errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

When I try to create an Audience in the Firebase console, the following message appears and the creation is not executed.

One or more of your fields contain invalid characters.

I could not find any information about this message in the official documentation.
Do you have any idea why the message is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify this in my environment.
It seems to occur at least when Event contains Japanese characters.

I can set Japanese in the event, but it seems that cannot create Audience that contains Japanese.

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm not an Analytics expert, but that sounds unexpected. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.